# Missing number in a circle?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, number-sequence

Here in this circle there are seven segments. 6 numbers have been written in 6 segments following a particular pattern. Find the number which will replace ??? in the seventh segment and also describe the pattern that you have derived.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I think [MisterEman22's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/20402/12700) is better, I have an alternate solution.

> The missing number should be **51**.

How I arrived at this number,

> Starting with the number 15, we add twice of the next number clockwise to get the number in the next sector. Then we choose that sector as the first sector and repeat. So, 
> **15** + 2 x **3** = **21**
> **21** + 2 x **6** = **33**
> And following the formula again gives
> **33** + 2 x **9** = **51**

Comment: Correct Answer.

Answer (score 5):

Answer is:

> 39

Explanation:

> Starting with the part that has 3 in it, every other square clockwise is $3*n$ where $n$ is the next prime number. So:
> $3*1=3$
> $3*2=6$
> $3*3=9$
> $3*5=15$
> $3*7=21$
> $3*11=33$
> $3*13=39$

Comment: This seems to be the intended answer, but 1 is not a prime

Comment: @Anachor Wow I completely overlooked that. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Try Again.Good try though

Comment: Of course, there is always [this](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C7%2C11%2C13&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: You could just say n are non-composite natural numbers

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

> 45

Explanation:

> 3 + 3 = 6
>  6 + 3 = 9
>  9 + 6 = 15
>  15 + 6 = 21
>  21 + 12 = 33
>  33 + 12 = 45

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:

> 30

................................

> [image]

Comment: That works for any cricle with any numbers inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be:

> 13

Because

> 15 + 3 + 21 + 6 + 33 + 9 + n = 100

This is likely not the true answer, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that this is the correct answer, because of the simple explanation:

> 39

For each pair of adjacent numbers, caluclate $\text{largest number} - 2*\text{smallest number}$

$15-2*3 = 9$, 9 is already in the circle
$21-2*3 = 15$, 15 is already in the circle
$21-2*6 = 9$, 9 is already in the circle
$33-2*6 = 21$, 21 is already in the circle
$33-2*9 = 15$, 15 is already in the circle

The only values for the missing number that follow this rule are: $3$, $33$, and $39$. The circle already contains $3$ and $33$, so we'll use $39$.